# Variables in combination with formulas

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA Excel I'm using a combination of variables and a function to be posted in a cell. The variable is containing a value, and the function is a "sum" function.

The variables used is "OB" for the value and "lastrow" for the row number.

When I try to get VBA to write the formula both these are working separately:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[+1]C:R[" & lastrow & "]C)"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = OB
```

...but when I try to combine them I get all different types of syntax problem (trying to deduct the sum function from the value in the cell):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = OB - "=SUM(R[+1]C:R[" & lastrow & "]C)"
```

Can anyone help me on the syntax to get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & OB & "-SUM(R[+1]C:R[" & lastrow & "]C)"
```

Comment: unfortunately this gives a run time error (I tried that before as well)